# Linux/Qt - Error creating SSL Context (error: 140A90C4 ...)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ssl

Trying to set up a TCP-Server with a SSL-Encryption via QSslSocket in Qt5 on a Ubuntu 17.04 System. When I connect with a client QAbstractSocket throws out the following error:

*Error creating SSL context (error:140A90C4:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_new:null ssl method passed, error:140A90C4:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_new:null ssl method passed)*

Here are some things I already found in other threats:

```
qDebug() << "SSL Support: " << QSslSocket::supportsSsl();
qDebug() << "Compile Time: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString();
qDebug() << "Run Time: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString();
```

gives out:

```
SSL Support:  true
Compile Time:  "OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016"
Run Time:  "OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016"
```

When I run `openssl version` in the terminal, I get `OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016` as answer.

Anyone any idea how to fix that error?

Comment: Please clarify the question: are you developing both client and server on Qt? Are you running them on the same machine (same openssl version)? How are you setting SSL configuration parameters, certificates, protocol version etc..

Answer (score 3):

Try to install a new library.
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev

see: https://github.com/subutai-io/control-center/issues/528